# C - '\n' character not printing new line

Tags: c, string, character, buffer, newline

I am passing a string such as "abc\n" to a program that stores in a string in a buffer, and then printing what was passed in.

Like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   char buffer[5];
   strncpy(buffer, argv[1], 5);
   printf("%s", buffer);

   return 0;
}
```

My argument is then this: `"abc\n"`

But then the string that prints out is this: `abc\n`

How come it doesn't add a new line after abc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it prints `abc\n` is that the shell does not do C-style escaping, i.e. `\n` in the shell is not an escaped newline. And *what the shell produces* is what is passed as an argument to `main` in your C program.

`char * str = "abc";` simply doesn't have the same behavior as `foo abc\n` in a shell terminal. The former is specified by the C standard, and the latter may vary from shell to shell.

How exactly to fix it, depends on your platform, and what shell you use, and it's not really a `C` question.

You might want to explain exactly what you are trying to do, and then you can consider whether to manually implement certain character escape combinations, or to use a different input method.

Here's the code example on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/111f9fdd28219f88

(Here's the code and command line:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   char buffer[5];
   strncpy(buffer, argv[1], 5);
   printf("%s", buffer);

   return 0;
}
```

> g++ -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror main.cpp && ./a.out "asd\n"
>
> asd\n

Comment: I see thanks. I am using the GCC compiler, I think my shell is not bash, but the regular sh one.

Comment: @Ikshvaku:  Doesn't matter -- neither bash nor ordinary sh interprets backslash(`\ `) escapes in strings. so `\n` will be two characters.  Outside of quotes, `\ ` has special meaning to the shell, but not the same as in C strings, so it won't work there either.  However, you CAN include actual newlines in strings in sh and bash -- type `./a.out "asd` and hit enter and you'll get a continuation prompt (usually `>`), and you can enter more text for the same command.  Type `"` and hit enter now, and it will invoke your program with a newline in the argument.

Comment: Note; `strncpy(buffer, "abc\\n", 5); printf("%s", buffer);` is UB as `buffer` lacks a null character.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass in "abc\n" from a command line, you're passing in a literal "\" followed by a literal "n", which is what you're doing.

When you define a string in a program as

```
char *myString = "abc\n";
```

The "\n" gets converted to a newline at compile time.